# google maps click event isn't reading objects from data

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, event-listener

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude by clicking on map then I use them to get formatted address from google maps API and finally I want to persist lat, lng and formatted address in my object "station" declared in data

```js
data() {
    return {
        station: {},
        mapName: this.name + "-map",
        lat: Number,
        lng: Number,
        Fulladdress: String
    };
}  ,  
mounted() {
    const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName);
    const options = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.501527, -0.1921837)
    };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
      this.lat = event.latLng.lat();
      this.lng = event.latLng.lng();

      axios
        .get(
          "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +
            this.lat +
            "," +
            this.lng +
            "&key=APIKEY"
        )
        .then(resp => {
          var fulladdress;
          console.log(resp.data.results[0].formatted_address);
          fulladdress = resp.data.results[0].formatted_address;
          this.Fulladdress = fulladdress;

        //persist lat, lng and formatted address in my object station 
        this.station.address = this.Fulladdress;
        this.station.lat = this.lat;
        this.station.lng = this.lng;

        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });

      });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is changing. Inside the click handler, the `this` is not referring to the Vue instance, but something else (it depends on how google maps does it, but it could be `window` or the map instance).

To have the `this` be the Vue instance, use arrow functions instead.

Change from:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", (event)  => {
```